# Is there any way to put a footnote in MPDF document?

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I would like to put a footnote in my PDF, created by MPDF from html. I didn't find any function or tag for that. I tried put notes in footer, changing it by  tag, but that was changing footers for all even/odd pages. Maybe is there a way to change footer starting from next page? Then I would change footer with my note text and immediately after change it to standard footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$mpdf->SetFooter('{DATE d/m/Y }|{PAGENO}/{nb}|Sym Consultoria');
```